# Selenium can't find radio button

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, servicenow

I'm automating the testing process we have in servicenow, but I can't select a radio button in a form. I've used multiple selectors to fix this but nothing has worked.

ServiceNow HTML:

[image: ServiceNow HTML]

these are the selectors I have used:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[value="Add"]').click()
```

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@value="Add"]').click()
```

None of these have worked and there's not iframe tag in the body to swicth to. Thank you!

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: @cruisepandey This is the error: `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"input[value="Add"]"} (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.124)` But the radio button is there as you can see in the link

Comment: Can you share a link to the web page?

Comment: @Prophet it's behind a login page only accessible by a few people. I don't think there's a way I could do

Comment: Check if there is an iframe there

Comment: @Prophet That was my first guess too, but there's no iframe tag in the page

Comment: It's hard to guess what is the problem without seeing the page HTML at least. Better is to debug it with real code with IDE...

Comment: I've run into this kind of thing before where I swear the element should be there but selenium can't find it.  At that point I would dump the HTML to see what selenium sees just to confirm it's looking at the same thing I am.  
Maybe try that?

Comment: @MarcelWilson How would I do that? I've been trying to resolve this for the past day, so I'd try anything

Comment: `print(driver.page_source)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with expicit wait  :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@value='Add']")))
element.click()
```

**Imports  :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Update 1 :**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
radioBtn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@value='Add']")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].checked = true;", radioBtn)
```

Comment: This is the error now: `element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@value='Add']")))
  , line 80, in until       
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)   
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: `

Comment: can you check for iframe or framset or simply frame ? it could be present

Comment: That was my first guess too. There's only one iframe tag in the html and it's way below where the radio button is

Comment: Can you check that in dev tool (chrome ) by pressing F12 and go to element section, do a CTRL + F and search for that xpath

Comment: I did and searched for "frame" using CTRL+F and it brought up the iframe tag I mentioned earlier

Comment: no I want you to check `//input[@value='Add']` this xpath

Comment: I did and it found the input tag of the radio button

Comment: is it 1/1  match ?

Comment: It is. It's highlighting exactly what I'm trying to grab

Comment: I have updated the code above under `updated 1`  section, can you try that and share your experience ?

Comment: This is the error now: `radioBtn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@value='Add']")))
  File, line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:` Also thank you so much for your help

Comment: instead of `"arguments[0].checked = true;"`, can you just try `"arguments[0].click();"`

Comment: Where is this radio button in the UI  ?

Comment: It's in a form and there are three of them: add, update, remove. When you select any of them, it automatically updates the form based on what you picked

Comment: I meant to ask, is it in bottom or in left or top ?

Comment: What do you mean by that? There're three radio buttons right next to each other. My guess is that these radio buttons are being generated by JS, so that's why I'm having this issue

Comment: where they are present in the UI ? are they present in top bar, or in left hand side menu if there's any .  I think I am being very simple

Comment: I sent you an email showing what it looks like

Answer (score 0):

The following are a few reasons why I couldn't find an element.

1. Currently on the wrong window/frame.
2. Synchronization issues - script is looking before the element has loaded.  Solved with explicit waits. (see @cruisepandey's answer)
3. The element was different due to mobile vs desktop. Should be noticable if you disable headless.  I advise dumping the HTML from selenium just to be sure.

When I'm unsure I'll start trying to find it's parent element, walking up the scope until I'm able to get a proper element.  That's usually where I figure out what the problem was.

- Can I find the parent label element?
- Can I find the grandparent div element?
- Can I find the greatgrandparent fieldset?
- And so on...

Comment: I dumped the html into an text file, but all I'm seeing is JS code and barely any HTML. I tried to look for the radio button, but couldn't find anything

Comment: You'll have to figure out *why* but that would certainly explain the lack of finding the radio button.

Comment: Try looking at `driver.window_handles` vs `driver.current_window_handle`?  Or try resetting which frame you're in.  Is it possible you're in the iframe from a previous step?